# supplying command options to system binaries whose paths are stored in variables in perl

Tags: bash, perl

I am having difficulty finding the correct syntax for executing system binaries via Perl.

The following works as expected:

```
perl -e 'system(ls);'
```

The following does not work unless quotes are supplied around the binary's path:

```
perl -e 'system(/bin/ls);'
```

Given my understanding of the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), in both cases, the argument to `system` is a single scalar without [shell metacharacters](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-metacharacter), so the result should be the same. Moreover, since the perl command is enclosed by single quotes, shell interpolation can be ruled out as a problem.

Options can be supplied to the command by various means, utilizing either its short name or the full path:

```
perl -e 'system("ls", "-l");'
perl -e 'my @args = ("ls","-l"); system(@args);'
perl -e 'my @args = ("/bin/ls","-l"); system(@args);'
```

However, options fail if the binary path is stored in a variable:

```
perl -e 'my $ls = `which ls`; system($ls, "-l");'
perl -e 'my $ls = `which ls`; system("$ls", "-l");'
perl -e 'my $ls = `which ls`; my @args = ($ls,"-l"); system(@args);'
perl -e 'my $ls = `which ls`; my @args = ("$ls","-l"); system(@args);'
```

Storing the path of the binary in a variable is acceptable provided that options are omitted:

```
perl -e 'my $ls = `which ls`; system($ls);'
```

On the other hand, options can be used with a variable containing the name of a binary:

```
perl -e 'my $ls = "ls"; my @args = ($ls,"-l"); system(@args);'
```

As can be discerned, I have been trying to determine the syntax for storing the path of a binary in a variable, and then executing a system call to that binary with options. I would appreciate enlightenment on the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the answer was simply that `which` appends a newline to the path of the binary, which must be removed:

```
$ perl -e 'my $ls = `which ls`; chomp($ls); system("$ls", "-l");'
```

Rather than delete the post, I'll leave it here for the benefit of future users who may encounter the same problem.

I would still be interested to know why quotes are required around "/bin/ls" and not "ls", as mentioned at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why quotes are required around:

```
perl -e 'system(/bin/ls);'
```

is because a bare `/` is seen as the start of a regular expression, and defaults to the *match-operator* (`m`).  As [perlop](http://perldoc.co.uk/perlop.html) says:

m/PATTERN/msixpogc

/PATTERN/msixpogc

*Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails. If no string is specified via the =~ or !~ operator, the $_ string is searched.*

But, I hear you ask, why didn't it throw a warning?  Because you don't have warnings set:

```
perl -we 'system(/bin/ls);'
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the '-w' option for `use warnings;` for one-liners. I always include it in scripts though.

Comment: The `-w` is the old way of switching-on warnings, but still supported.  `use warnings;` (introduced at 5.6) is preferred in a script because it is controllable and is more explicit.